# Broken Rinkeby Faucet, tried both platforms 4 times - anyone have any spare Rinkeby ETH?

Tags: testnets, rinkeby

Any help appreciated, I'll keep trying otherwise.

0xd1e037B287d7193ccb7B39584B380be28aD69fe6

Comment: You know that you should share your ETH address via Twitter and then paste Twitter post URL in the Faucet right?

Comment: sent some ETH your way :)